# Error in MICE package in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I am getting the error when i run the below code for imputing the missing values through MICE package in R

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Cars93_miss.csv"
ca <- read.csv(url)
im_ca <- mice(ca, MaxNWts = 4000)

iter imp variable
  1   1  Manufacturer  Model
Error in augment(y, ry, x, ...) : 
  Maximum number of categories (50) exceeded
```

Could someone help me as why am i getting this error? Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: It seems like one of the imputation procedures can't handle factors with more than 50 levels. Your data set has many of those. In addition, the data set has 93 rows, and `Model` (the variable at which the error is thrown) is a factor with 92 levels and one `NA`. I don't think it even makes sense to impute that.

Comment: @SimonG Thanks SimonG for the clarification.